# Создать массив из всех возможных букв от a до j   (в аски симвлоах)

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста создать некий цикл который будет генерировать двумерный массив где будут записаны все возможные кобинации в первом столбце и их аски номера в другом
Максимальное количество букв - 12
алфавит от a-j
Должно получится  такой массив двумерный массив

```
    a 97
    b 98
    ...
    ...
    aa 97 97
    ab 97 98

    ....
    ....
```

и так до jjjjjjjjjjjj

Comment: @Not even close, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Это и есть часть которая у меня не получилась :D. Для справки.Полное задание это подбор пароля по хешу) Единсвенное решение которое я придумал это сделать радужную таблицу всех паролей а потом искать по ней

Comment: Вы хотите сгенерить все возможные пароли да 12 букв?

Объем представляете?

Comment: Да представляю) но там же не весь алфовит на только первые 10 символов от а до j те 10^6 что не так уж и много

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос: а зачем вам коды-то отдельно? Если сама по себе буква - уже и есть свой код. И вопрос номер два: "и их аски номера в другом" это как? Какого типа данные должны быть во втором столбце?

Comment: можно ли вопрос ешё глупее. Можно ли допустим перевести строку abc в 979899. Аски номера мне нужны для преобразование их в хеш. Формула для преобразования в h(s)=s0+s1p+s2p2+...+sn-1pn-1

Comment: >Можно ли допустим перевести строку abc в 979899

И что мешает это сделать не создавая дополнительных данных?

Answer (score 4):

Будь мыжиком - пиши как мужик.

```
 char c = 'a';
 uint16_t t = 0xffff;
 while(--t)
     fprintf(stderr, "%c%c%c%c\n", (c+((t >> 12) & 0xf)), (c+((t >> 8) & 0xf)), (c+((t >> 4) & 0xf)), (c+((t >> 0) & 0xf)));
```

Я уже сплю - мне лень, по такому же принципу пили на сколько угодно себе символов-мисивов.